# Python MySQLClient installation fails with "metadata-generation-failed"

Tags: python, mysql

Well, I have "googled it" without finding an answer.  Routine updates of a Python-based site, based on its `requirements.txt`,  now fail with **metadata-generation-failed** when attempting to update "mysqlclient."  The question is why.

Comment: Please, before anyone "votes this question off the island," will anyone please explain to me what the "metadata" is, and how it is generated, and why such a process might "fail?" Before I "dumpster-dive into the script code" to find out for myself, it seems perfectly reasonable for me to ... ask politely.

Comment: You will have to provide much more details.

Comment: I have no idea what `metdata` it uses but maybe with FULL error message it could be  simpler to guess it.

Comment: To a Python programmer this question is perfectly clear.  The "pip" update process is handing back an error-message from a subprocess.  And the text of that message is literally: `metadata-generation-failed`. And the package being installed is `mysqlclient`.

Comment: Problem SOLVED.  See below.

Comment: what package is in the requirements.txt that is causing this to fail?

Answer (score 12):

*Robinson`s* answer is correct, but also maybe you forgot to install **MySQL development headers and libraries** like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

details: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Answer (score 6):

The relevant message text was as follows:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/zv/60vkqgms41v8zg76_n8rntg00000gn/T/pip-install-_nlyaw6p/mysqlclient_a781e05976524422b764a6902ff6fe88/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/private/var/folders/zv/60vkqgms41v8zg76_n8rntg00000gn/T/pip-install-_nlyaw6p/mysqlclient_a781e05976524422b764a6902ff6fe88/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/private/var/folders/zv/60vkqgms41v8zg76_n8rntg00000gn/T/pip-install-_nlyaw6p/mysqlclient_a781e05976524422b764a6902ff6fe88/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

And this is what provided the clue:  **mysql_config: command not found**

I **solved** the problem by locating where the command was on my system, and adding it to the `$PATH`, which in my case was as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql-5.7.16-osx10.11-x86_64/bin:$PATH
```

Apparently the meaning of this message is that a command to configure mysql could not be found on the $PATH. Now we know.

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

> Version of python within `python3.10-dev` should be the version of python you use. In my case it was `3.10`:
>
> ```bash
> $ python3 --version
> Python 3.10.6
> ```

### Details

First, I ran @levinson's command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then during `pip install -r requirements.txt` I got other errors (inherited one another):

```bash
Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
<...>
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
<...>
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
<...>
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
```

After that, I found [this article](https://sebhastian.com/failed-building-wheel-mysql-python/#:%7E:text=Fix%20Failed%20building%20wheel%20MySQL%20for%20Linux) which suggests executing this command:

```bash
# For Debian/ Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

But it gives me error while installing `python3-dev`. After that I found out that there's a `python3.x-dev` packages and tried `3.10` version. And it worked! After that I just ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` and the installation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still helpful. In my case I realized that

`sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev`

was installing the mysql client but not the mysql server. I installed the mysql server with:

`sudo apt install mysql-server`

and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

follow this steps in terminal!!!

1. brew install mysql
2. brew install openssl
3. export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
4. sudo xcode-select --reset
5. pip install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the requirements.txt is holding an 'import mysql' statement, [MySQL documentation](https://pypi.org/project/mysql/) help resolves this issue in two ways:

1. Since mysql is a 'virtual package' install "MySQL-python (Python 2) or mysqlclient (Python 3)"
2. Resolve [OS specific install dependencies](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

Once the dependencies are installed you can avoid code any rewriting by installing the mysql package.