# Unable to install mysqlclient using virtualenv (Fedora 37)

Tags: python, pip, libmysqlclient

I am developing an app using Django 4 and have set up a virtual environment using venv. The problem is that I cannot get the MySQL client package installed using pip to allow my Django app to connect to an existing MariaDB hosted on the same server.

**I am using Fedora 37, Python 3.11.1 .**

Every time I try to install mysqlclient via pip within my virtual environment I the below error:

> (venv) $ pip install mysqlclient Collecting mysqlclient   Using cached
> mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)   Preparing metadata (setup.py) ...
> error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [18 lines of output]
> /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
> /bin/sh: line 1: mariadb_config: command not found
> /bin/sh: line 1: mysql_config: command not found
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 2, in 
> File "", line 34, in 
> File "/tmp/pip-install-fuegkdx1/mysqlclient_d3182534a7ce4d10ae4bceac47107c54/setup.py",
> line 15, in 
> metadata, options = get_config()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/tmp/pip-install-fuegkdx1/mysqlclient_d3182534a7ce4d10ae4bceac47107c54/setup_posix.py",
> line 70, in get_config
> libs = mysql_config("libs")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "/tmp/pip-install-fuegkdx1/mysqlclient_d3182534a7ce4d10ae4bceac47107c54/setup_posix.py",
> line 31, in mysql_config
> raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
> OSError: mysql_config not found
> mysql_config --version
> mariadb_config --version
> mysql_config --libs
> [end of output]
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above
> for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

Comment: Have you tried answer of this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358693/unable-to-install-python-mysqlclient-oserror-mysql-config-not-found or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72538597/python-mysqlclient-installation-fails-with-metadata-generation-failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%2Fbin%2Fsh%3A+line+1%3A+mysql_config%3A+command+not+found

Comment: Esp. see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22013331/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/28414414/7976758