# How can I expire a MySQL wait timeout?

Tags: mysql, connection

I've read the MySQL docs, and other SO questions didn't answer my question.

- [visited question 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162453/mysql-difference-between-wait-timeout-and-connect-timeout),
- [visited question 2 - while connection polling and facing error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893339/16444406) ,
- [visited question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74053037/16444406)

I've set MySQL's `GLOBAL wait_timeout` to `600` seconds, which means it'll end in 10 minutes. and it was ending in 14 minutes, as I've tested; I've attached the response error image.
[image]

Here is image of setting global `wait_timeout`
[image]

What is happening now? I've visited some questions to implement connection polling, where I found some solutions.
but when I performed those solutions, `wait_timeout` stopped working. which is becoming my headache. I want `wait_timeout` to be ended at the time I've set, but it's not ending. see the picture below the `wait_timeout` is not getting updated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after researching more deeply, I've found my mistake was to not use the workbench and knowledge of `wait_timeout` working.

So, here is what I found.

**When a global variable is modified in the current session but not persistent, MySQL displays the persistent value rather than the updated value (in the terminal). (But one can see it changing on the workbench.)**

**A workbench image**

[image]

**Mean While in the terminal,**

[image]

**Both in the same time**

[image]

**When one uses the `SET GLOBAL` command to change a global variable, changes are made instantly for the current session but are not saved to the MySQL configuration file. If one ends the session or restarts the MySQL server, the variable's original value will be utilized.**

---

MySql `waits` information,

`wait_timeout` is a global variable that sets the timeout for idle client connections. It applies to all client connections, regardless of the protocol used (including X Protocol connections). When a client connection is idle (i.e., not executing any queries) for longer than the specified `wait_timeout`, the connection is closed by the server.

`mysqlx_interactive_timeout` is also a global variable that sets the timeout for interactive sessions that use the MySQL X Protocol. It applies only to X Protocol connections and is used to set the maximum duration of an interactive session between the client and the server. An interactive session is defined as a session that has issued at least one statement, but has not issued a statement that requires a longer timeout, such as a long-running query or a transaction. When the `mysqlx_interactive_timeout` value is exceeded, the session is closed by the server.

`mysqlx_wait_timeout` is another global variable that sets the timeout for client connections that use the MySQL X Protocol. It applies only to X Protocol connections and is used to set the maximum duration of a client's wait time for the server to send a response. When the `mysqlx_wait_timeout` value is exceeded, the client connection is closed by the server.

In summary, `wait_timeout` sets the timeout for idle client connections, `mysqlx_interactive_timeout` sets the timeout for interactive sessions that use the X Protocol, and `mysqlx_wait_timeout` sets the timeout for client connections that use the X Protocol while waiting for a response.

Answer (score 1):

Note, in particular, `SET GLOBAL` (for *nost* settings) has no effect on users that are currently logged in.  It will be inherited by anyone logging in after that.

`wait_timeout` is tricky.  Interactive/batch, GLOBAL/SESSION/not-yet-relogged-in.

Sorry, but I can't figure out which one to set in which situation.

Comment: no problem, that means a lot I'll try to figure it out,

Comment: it's client Interactive and has scopes global and sessions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: I've tried running this command ```SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;```,

Comment: @M.AbdullahIqbal - That `SHOW` will provide values that will be used _the next time_ you log in.  (They will be used to initialize the `SESSION VARIABLES`.)